# Batch: Search a word in txt file and return last line number where it has been seen

Tags: batch-file, search, for-loop, numbers, line

I have a list of items in a txt file where certain words is written a few times. I did a batch file that search this text and return the line number where the specified word is. However it only gives the number where it has been seen first but I would like the opposite, I would like it to return where it has been seen for last time.

Here is my list in List.txt:

```
Marcel
Maurice
Melane
Bob
Melane
```

And this script return me "3", while I would like to only have "5":

```
set "textfile=C:SomewhereInMyPC\List.txt"
for /F %SKIP% "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /i /x /n Melane "%textfile%"') do set line=%%N
echo %line%
pause
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot, really appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `/x` and use `findstr /i /n Melane "%textfile%"`

Comment: That's actually just a work-around of a bug (?) of `findstr`, which does _not_ consider the last line a (exact) match using the `/X` switch, unless it is terminated with a new-line; without `/X`, there is no difference with respect to the final new-line; however, `/X` specifies that the _whole_ line must match, so _not_ stating the switch makes every line _containing_ the search string to be considered a match, so the intrinsic function of the batch script has changed! @tref should specify what is wanted.